# Showing that the functional integration is a linear functional as follows

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $C([a,b])$ be a set of all continous function on $[a,b]$. Let $J:C([a,b]) \to \Bbb R$ be a functional. Then, the integral
\begin{equation*}
J[h] = \int_a^b h(x) \ dx
\end{equation*}
defines a linear functional on $C([a,b])$ for all function $h(x) \in C([a,b])$.

**Attempts:**

1. Let $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ be an arbitrary. Then,
   \begin{equation*}
   J[\alpha h] = \int_a^b (\alpha h)(x) dx = \alpha \int_a^b h(x) dx = \alpha J[h].
   \end{equation*}
2. For any $h_1,h_2 \in C([a,b])$,
   \begin{equation*}
   J[h_1+h_2] = \int_a^b (h_1+h_2)(x) dx = \int_a^b h_1(x) + h_2(x) dx = \int_a^b h_1(x) dx + \int_a^b h_2(x) dx = J[h_1] + J[h_2].
   \end{equation*}
3. Want to show: $J[h]$ is continuous at $\hat{h} \in C([a,b])$.
   Given any $\varepsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\varepsilon}{(b-a)}\}$ such that for all $h \in C([a,b])$ with $|| h - \hat{h} || < \delta$,
   \begin{align*}
   |J[h] - J[\hat{h}]| &= |\int_a^b h(x) dx - \int_a^b \hat{h}(x) dx | \\
   &= |\int_a^b (h(x) - \hat{h}(x)) dx | \\
   &\le \int_a^b |h-\hat{h}| \ dx \\
   &\le \int_a^b \max_{a\le x \le b} |h-\hat{h}| \ dx \\
   &= \int_a^b || h-\hat{h} || \ dx \\
   &< \varepsilon.
   \end{align*}

Hence, by definition, the above integral defines a linear functional on $C([a,b])$.

My question is, does the third part correct? I still have a little bit confusing on choosing $\delta$. When we use the minimum, and when we use directly, say $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{b-a}$ ?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct. While it's not wrong, you don't have to take the minimum in that particular case.

Comment: Thanks. But, can't I use that $\delta = \varepsilon/(b-a)$ directly, without using the minimum? Why?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Can you enlighten me about my confusing above? I still didn't get it yet right now. :(

Comment: None of the inequalities change when you omit the minimum so you can do it. Taking the minimum might make sense, for example, when there is a square involved.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Aah, I see. So, for the above (third part), could I use $\delta =\varepsilon/(b-a)$ directly? Since there is no square form.

Comment: Of course. Also, as a more general remark, to prove that a linear functional is continuous it suffices to prove that it is bounded and most of the times this is a bit easier to prove.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Thanks, Sir. It has to be clear right now.

Comment: Note : I've added the tag proof-verification to the question. Note that if you have a proof  that you wrote, and you want to focus on whether specific parts of the proof are correct or not, then you can tag your question proof-verification.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Noted. Thank you.